# python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory when compose docker

Tags: python, docker, flask

I run two different Apps in containers.

1. Django App
2. Flask App

Django ran just well. I configured my Flask App as follow:

This Is a docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8001:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_USER: username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33067:3306
```

This also is my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app

CMD python main.py
```

Problem: When I run
`docker-compose up` the following error occurs

```
backend_1  | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't know why it tries to open `manage.py` file since it is Flask and not Django App. I need your help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: manage.py is probably at the root of your project (same dir as requirements.txt) have you tried adding `COPY manage.py /app/manage.py` to your dockerfile?  And is this flask or django?

Comment: @TenaciousB  ```manage.py``` is at django project, a very different folder from a flask app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how this will work for you but, I resolved this by changing my docker-compose.yml to have a command parameter, so it looks like this

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: 'python main.py' << Updated Line >>
    ports:
      - 8001:5000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: main
      MYSQL_USER: username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pwd
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pwd
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33067:3306
```

Answer (score 0):

I started a new Flask app(but this time on virtualenv) and my problem fixed :)